# Easiest way to make a smaller screen resolution version of my Windows Form / Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, screen-resolution

I have written a C# windows form application that is designed for a 1280x1024 screen. It is completely full of controls. I need to make a "light" version for a 1024x600 screen that works off the same code base for use on a netbook.  The easiest way I can think to do this is to #ifdef the design file and define some variable to pick at build time & make multiple builds, but I would prefer to have a second project in my solution that inherits everything from the first form and use the designer to re-arrange the various list boxes, text boxes etc, maybe make a couple tabs to hold the less pertinent information.   What is the easiest way to do this in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 3):

That's what [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property is for. You need to set it for controls you wish to be resized.

From MSDN:

> Use the `Anchor` property to define how a control is automatically resized as its parent control is resized. Anchoring a control to its parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent control is resized.
>
> You can anchor a control to one or more edges of its container. For example, if you have a `Form` with a `Button` whose `Anchor` property value is set to `Top` and `Bottom`, the `Button` is stretched to maintain the anchored distance to the top and bottom edges of the `Form` as the `Height` of the `Form` is increased.

Comment: Or you can make multiple forms, then show the appropriate one by using the current screen resolution.

Comment: Well, you *could* do that, but that means you are repeating code, violating the DRY principle. You end up with two forms you need to maintain.

Comment: @QuanticProgramming - That is the single worst programming idea I have seen suggested on this website.

Comment: Yeah that is not at all what I want to do.  The problem is that the screen is completely full of controls as it is.  I have to take some away and shrink the size of a couple (namely the webbrowser & datagridview that are there)

Comment: @analog123: for these two controls, try setting the `Anchor` property to all four sides (`Left`,`Right`,`Top`,`Bottom`). Of course, if one of them is at the left side, you will not anchor it to the right. Controls which are below should be anchored to the bottom part of the form, and those at the right to the right part of the screen. You can get an example in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2231/Working-with-Anchoring-and-Docking-Properties). A vertical `SplitContainer` also might be useful, if you dock these controls inside its left and right panels.

Comment: This might be helpful, but it really doesn't solve my general question which is I would like to completely redesign the form using the original code base.   I don't want to break anything by abstracting out the form either.  I don't understand why it isn't possible to just inherit the form and relayout the existing controls.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news for you is that there really is no quick and easy solution. When you are working with a smaller form factor like a netbook or slate, there are specific User Experience elements that you will need to pay attention to that will not translate very well between the two environments.

With that said, if you create a base form with all of your logic, you can inherit from it for each screen form factor, and design the two forms separately.

If you follow this path, there is a bug in Visual Studio when connecting up event handlers to events in the designer - it will not allow you to connect to an event handler located in a parent class. The designer will crash. To get around this problem, manually wire up your event handlers as follows:

```
    this.MyButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MyClickEventHandler);
```

Good luck!

Comment: I have to give this answer a downvote for this 100% false statement. **-- "The bad news for you is that there really is no quick an easy solution."**

Comment: Ramhound, what's your suggestion then?  So far I like my ifdef solution the best.  I can just create a new form, design it using the same variable names, copy & paste the design code and block it out depending on the build.   I was hoping all I had to do was something like inherit the entire class, and then re-arrange the controls using the designer.

Comment: @Ramhound - how is that false? I don't know of any product or tool that will automatically fix this. The quick and easy solutions using docking and anchoring work - up to a point, but based on the needs - changing the overall look of the form, substantially - will not meet  analog123's needs. Having two separate layouts is, in my opinion, the best solution, but it will take a lot of work to avoid code duplication, which is too easy in WinForms. As a side note - I am assuming one build and deployment here - detecting the screen size at runtime.